# Only have remove buttons for some rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have a handsontable with data that would have a property that indicates a specific status (`hasShipped` if specifics are required). Is there a way to remove the "remove row" button from a row where the `hasShipped` value is `true`?

Table definition, in case it's important:

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
            data: hotData,
            dataSchema: { Product: null, UOM: "EA", QtyShipped: 0 },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'Product',
                    title: "Product",
                    type: "text",
                    readOnly: isShipped 
                },
                {
                    data: 'UOM',
                    title: "UOM",
                    readOnly: true,
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    data: 'QtyShipped',
                    title: "Qty<br />Shipped",
                    type: "numeric",
                    readOnly: isShipped 
                }],
            allowInsertRow: true,
            //allowRemoveRow: true, //TODO: Depending on mode and row
            autoWrapCol: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            columnSorting: { column: 0, sortOrder: false },
            contextMenu: ['undo', 'redo', 'row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row'],
            currentColClassName: 'activeCol',
            currentRowClassName: 'activeRow',
            dropdownMenu: true,
            fixedColumnsLeft: 1,
            outsideClickDeselects: false,
            readOnly: <%= IsWatchList.ToString().ToLower() %>,
            removeRowPlugin: true,
            rowHeaders: true,
            stretchH: "all", //used in conjunction #hot-container styling to make the table take up 100% of parent width
        });
```

Comment: I have no experience with this particular library but you will probably need some combination of [listening for the `contextMenu`](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/tutorial-callbacks.html) and [dynamically changing settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617551/handsontable-dynamically-set-settings). <- I've updated the second link so check it out.

Comment: Huh, I can take out the context menu because it's not that important. But dynamically changing settings might be a good place to start since I'm already making cells in specific rows readonly depending on another property value. Thanks for the thought

Comment: My bad, in your question, "remove row" button is awfully ambiguous without a screenshot of some sort so I assumed you wanted to grey out the contextMenu's "remove row" option when `hasShipped` is `true`

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot of what you are dealing with and point out which line of code is actually responsible for producing this "remove row" button then it would greatly help others to help you...

Comment: I just posted an answer and credited you. Check it out. If you want to grab that as an answer since you gave me the correct direction with dynamic settings, I'll accept it and delete mine.

Comment: Nah, I'm good. There was no possible way of me even half-guessing that answer based on your question so I upvoted you since you solved it yourself and my comments are technically unrelated to the solution, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Given that I was already implementing the code to remove a row and had altered the code to insert my own custom styled button, I knew where the buttons were being injected.

Thanks to [MonkeyZues's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191572/monkeyzeus) comment, I looked at the code where I was injecting the remove row button and, depending on the value of the `HasShipped` property, was able to inject (or not) the required row buttons

```
 if (jsonObject != "") {
      if (jsonObject.LoadDetails[row]["HasShipped"] == true) {
           div.appendChild(btnNode);
           elem.appendChild(div);
      }
 }
```